# Spring ERROR MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

Tags: angularjs, angular, spring

when i`m trying to upload image, i have the problem like this

ERROR 3080 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause

Here my Controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ifp9.png)

My angular html code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49SDA.png)

Comment: Try to set to content type as multipart on UI side while sending image data. 
something like following 

Content-Type: multipart/form-data;